# web app displaying blank screen in IE 7 - 9

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, requirejs

I'm working on a web app located at http://app.voxtracker.com/

The issue I'm facing is I get a blank white screen in IE 7-9 with no error message in my console.

I'm using requirejs and loading my javascript dependencies within my  tag. Any strategies for debugging IE nonsense?

I can also see from the IE9 console that after the initial get request for "/", no other assets are being loaded.

Here's my HTML output:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]><html lang="en" class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html lang="en" class="ie9"><![endif]--><!--[if !IE]><!-->

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Vox Tracker | Vox Supply Chain</title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <link href="/css?1363218849714" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/assets/img/favicon-vox.ico" rel="shortcut icon">
</head>

<body class="login">
    <div id="loading_indicator" style=
    "margin-top:-125px; position:absolute; top:50%; text-align:center; width:100%">
    <img src="/assets/img/loading_2.gif">

        <h2 id="status" style="font-style:italic">Loading...</h2>
    </div><script data-main="/source/client" src="/source/lib/require.js" type=
    "text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was using a nodejs module 'html-minifier' to minify my html output & it messed with the IE comment blocks at the top of the page.